# operand type clash int is incompatible with date in sql server

Tags: sql

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE2 
(
EMPLOYEEID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
FIRSTNAME VARCHAR(50)NULL,
LASTNAME VARCHAR(50)NULL,
SALARY bigint NOT NULL,
JOININGDATE DATE NOT NULL,
DEPARTMENTNAME VARCHAR(50)
)
```

This is the table I have created.
And I now want to insert the values given below.

```
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE2 (FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,SALARY,JOININGDATE,DEPARTMENTNAME)
VALUES('JOHN','ABRAHAM',1000000,2013-01-01,'BANKING'),
('MICHAEL','CLERK',800000,2013-01-01,'INSURENCE'),
('ROY','THOMOS',700000,2013-01-01,'BANKING'),
('TOM','JOSE',600000,2013-02-01,'INSURENCE'),
('JERRY','PINTO',650000,2013-02-01,'INSURENCE'),
('PHILIP','MATHEW',750000,2013-01-01,'SERVICES'),
('TESTNAME1','123',650000,2013-01-01,'SERVICES'),
('JOHN','COOK',600000,2013-02-01,'INSURENCE');
```

But now I am getting an error like:

> Operand type clash: int is incompatible with date

Answer (score 3):

Put quotes around your date. i.e. '2013-01-01' not 2013-01-01.  It's treating them like integers and subtracting one from 2013 twice...